# Git desde linea de comandos en windows 7 no puede crear carpeta 'could not create /home/username/.ssh'

Tags: windows, git

En una instalacion nueva de git, cuando se setean las claves y todo usando tortoise git los repositorios se clonan correctamente. tambien funciona el comando pull y push sin problemas.

Sin embargo, cuando se abre una linea de comandos para hacer eso mismo, al ejecutar git pull (desde un cmd, power shell o mingw) tira un error parecido al siguiente. El error esta en la falta de acceso a la carpeta

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La carpeta esta creada en la ruta requerida (c:\users\u40497.ssh) sin embargo no la reconoce como valida.

Los permisos son correctos y las ventanas estan abiertas como administradores. Las claves estan correctas, porque desde tortoise las mismas funcionan. 
Las variables de entorno HOME y HOMEPATH apuntan a las rutas correctas.

Que es lo que puede estar pasando que no reconoce esa carpeta como valida?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Por alguna razón, tu instalación de [git](/questions/tagged/git) está buscando la carpeta `.ssh` dentro de `/home/u40497`.

Podés hacer un truquito... si estás usando [git for windows](https://git-for-windows.github.io/), el root que ve `mingw` está en `C:\Program Files\Git`. Lo que vamos a hacer es crear la carpeta `/home` que [git](/questions/tagged/git) está buscando.

En Windows:

1. Creá la carpeta `C:\Program Files\Git\home`
2. Cambiá los permisos como para que `Everyone` pueda escribir en ella

Abrí `mingw` y creá la carpeta que busca con este comando:

```
mkdir -p /home/u40497/.ssh
```

Y listo! si tenés claves privadas que necesitás que [git](/questions/tagged/git) use, las vas a tener que copiar a `C:\Program Files\Git\home\u40497\.ssh`.

Otra opción sería enseñarle a [git](/questions/tagged/git) dónde es tu home. Suena mucho más difícl de lo que realmente es.